# Evaluating expectation value in second quantization using Wick's theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, second-quantization, wick-theorem

I am working in the context of quantum chemistry. Given this expectation value in second quantization

$$
\langle 0 \vert [p^\dagger q, \kappa] \vert 0 \rangle
$$

with

$$
\kappa = \sum_{ai} k_{ai}(a^\dagger i - i^\dagger a)
$$

Indices $i,j,\ldots$ indicate occupied orbitals, $a,b,\ldots$ virtual orbitals, and $p,q,\ldots$ general orbitals (either occupied or not). The reference state $\vert 0 \rangle$ is the Fermi vacuum (not the true vacuum state).

Plugging in for $\kappa$, we get for the commutator

$$
[p^\dagger q, \kappa] = \sum_{ai} k_{ai} (p^\dagger q a^\dagger i - p^\dagger q i^\dagger a) - \sum_{bj} k_{bj} (b^\dagger j p^\dagger q - j^\dagger b p^\dagger q)
$$

In order to simplify this, I use Wick's theorem. The only types of contractions that are nonzero, are of the form

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{i}^\dagger \dot{j} &= \delta_{ij} \\
\dot{a} \dot{b}^\dagger &= \delta_{ab}
\end{align}
$$

Thus, in order to evaluate contractions between operators acting on unspecified orbitals, we must evaluate the different combinations. For the first string in the commutator above, I get that

$$
p^\dagger q a^\dagger i = \dot{p}^\dagger \ddot{q} \ddot{a}^\dagger \dot{i} = \delta_{ij}\delta_{ab}
$$

because we must have that $p\in \text{occ}$ and $q\in \text{virt}$ for the contraction to be nonzero.

I find the second string ($p^\dagger q i^\dagger a$) to be identical to the first one, thus cancelling the first sum. For the first string in the second term I find

$$
b^\dagger j p^\dagger q = 0
$$

because all possible contractions to me look like they should be zero. That leaves the final string, which I find to be

$$
j^\dagger b p^\dagger q = \{ \dot{j}^\dagger \ddot{b} \ddot{p}^\dagger \dot{q} \} = \delta_{jk}\delta_{bc}
$$

This is definitely not the correct. Where did I go wrong?

### UPDATE

Here is a more complete attempt at the solution:
In the second line I have performed a Baker-Campbell-Hausdorf expansion to first order (but note that I got the order of the commutator wrong, so my solution be valid up to a sign).

$$
\begin{align}
\tilde{D}_{pq}(\mathbf{\kappa}) =& \langle 0 \vert e^\kappa p^\dagger q e^{-\kappa} \vert 0\rangle \\
=& \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q \vert 0\rangle + \langle 0 \vert [p^\dagger q, \kappa] \vert 0 \rangle + \mathcal{O}(\kappa ^2) \\
=& \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q \vert 0 \rangle + \langle 0 \vert (p^\dagger q \kappa - \kappa p^\dagger q) \vert 0 \rangle \\
=& \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q \vert 0 \rangle + \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q \kappa \vert 0 \rangle - \langle 0 \vert \kappa p^\dagger q \vert 0\rangle \\
=& \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q \vert 0 \rangle + \sum\limits_{ai}k_{ai}\langle 0 \vert (p^\dagger q a^\dagger i - p^\dagger q i^\dagger a) \vert 0 \rangle - \sum\limits_{ai}k_{ai}\langle 0 \vert (a^\dagger i p^\dagger q - i^\dagger a p^\dagger q) \vert 0 \rangle \\
=& \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q | 0 \rangle + \sum\limits_{ai}k_{ai} \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q a^\dagger i \vert 0 \rangle - \sum\limits_{ai}k_{ai} \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q i^\dagger a \vert 0\rangle \\ 
 -& \sum\limits_{ai}k_{ai} \langle \vert a^\dagger i p^\dagger q \vert 0 \rangle + \sum\limits_{ai}k_{ai} \langle 0 \vert i^\dagger a p^\dagger q \vert 0 \rangle \\
=& \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q \vert 0 \rangle + k_{ai} - k_{ai} - 0 + k_{ai} \\
=& \langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q \vert 0 \rangle + k_{ai} \\
=& \delta_{ij} + k_{ai} \\
\langle 0 \vert p^\dagger q \vert 0 \rangle = \begin{cases} \delta_{pq} & p,q \in \text{occ} \\
0 & p \in \text{occ}, q \in \text{virt} \\ 
0 & p \in \text{virt}, q \in \text{occ} \\
0 & p,q \in \text{virt} \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: When you say that $p,q$ are *general orbitals*, does that mean that they can be both *occupied* and *virtual*? - this is to say that they should contract with occupied and virtual orbitals: $\dot{p}^\dagger \dot{i} = \delta_{pi}$, $\dot{p}^\dagger \dot{a} = \delta_{pa}$, etc.

Comment: I meant they are unspecified: they can be either occupied or unoccupied (but not both, they are mutually exclusive).

Comment: Also, your notation is not consistent, e.f., where do $k$ and $c$ appear from in the last contraction? - neither of them is present in the left-hand side of the equation. If you spell the math correctly step by step, your problem might go away.

Comment: I chose different because $j$ and $b$ ware already in use. I admit using indices confuse me a bit. They are dummy indices, so I thought I could simplify at the end by taking into account what they represent.

Comment: They are dummy indices when they are summed over, but not in the contraction as you wrote it. In other words, you are skipping mathematical steps and this frequently leads to errors. I am just trying to help you, since a) I do not understand where exactly is the problem, and b) it would be against the forum policy to post a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. See updated question for a more complete attempt at the solution.

Comment: Two comments on your update: a) If we follow Wick's theorem, all your contractions give the same contribution - there is no reason why one of them is suddenly zero; b) usually annihilation operators acting on the ground state give zero: $a|0\rangle =0$, etc. So all your contractions should be zero... but I am likely still confused by your notation.